# JS Interview Question: Is it always guaranteed that setTimeOut(function(){}, 5000) will execute after 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript

So I was recently asked this in a JS interview. He simply wrote a setTimeOut method with 5000 delay. He asked me if is it guaranteed that this will always get executed after 5 seconds.

I answered Yes. To which he told me that I was wrong. He told me to think in terms of JS event looping.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: AFAIK It's not guaranteed. It will only run if it can _after 5000ms_ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is javascript setTimeout guaranteed to fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491160/is-javascript-settimeout-guaranteed-to-fire)

Answer (score 3):

It could be that after the `setTimeout`, something else blocks the event loop from continuing - for example, with a `while(true)`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('running');
}, 5000);
while(true);
```

For a less drastic example, there could simply be something that's taking up a lot of resources before the timeout fires:

```js
console.log('start', performance.now());
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('running', performance.now());
}, 5000);

setTimeout(() => {
  // something expensive
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) {
  }
}, 4970);
```

In this case, the timeout still runs, but it takes moderately more than 5 seconds.

Keep in mind that `setTimeout` won't run *exactly* after 5 seconds anyway - there will be a *bit* of inaccuracy no matter what, maybe on the order of a few milliseconds (though more if other factors are taking up resources).